# How to get all users who upload photo in instagram for a specific location using location username or id?

Tags: c#, api, instagram

I want to get the list of users who has uploaded (shared) a photo on specific location (page)?
the user can type @location_user_name and then share the photo.
I want to get the user who share this photo from instagram api using location_user_name!
I tried the code below

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/" + this.instagram_id + "/media/recent?min_timestamp=" + dateString + "&access_token=XXX";
```

I got the photos uploaded by the location itself not users.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Instagram always returns the same data about Photos entity.

I have completed the following request:
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/41864127/media/recent/?client_id=my_client_id

And received the following response:

```
{
    "pagination": 
    { 
       ... 
    },
    "meta": { 
        "code": 200 
    },
    "data": [{
       ...
       "user" : {
           "username" : "annafaithxoxo",
           "website" : "",
           "profile_picture" : "https:\/\/igcdn-photos-a-a.akamaihd.net\/hphotos-ak-xaf1\/10748350_344686255703816_1812933634_a.jpg",
           "full_name" : "A\u035cn\u0361n\u0361a\u035c F\u0361a\u035ci\u035ct\u0361h\u0361",
           "bio" : "",
           "id" : "41864127"
      }
```

...

So, there is an information about a user in the end of Instagram Photo data object.
I am sure that it should be there in your case too :)
If you don't get it from the server then show me your example json response, please.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an implementation that does wha you want: http://www.gramfeed.com/instagram/places

You can search for a location, then view all pictures and get the usernames.

It used facebook places API to search for places at a location and then open the photos using the instagram endpoint:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/locations/<location_id>/media/recent?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```