# Query Instagram API by tag name to return location

Tags: python, instagram, instagram-api, folium

It was my goal to search Instagram media for a keyword (example "Eiffel Tower") and return results in the form location lat, long.
After researching it seems like there are two ways to do this: using media search but you must provide a location and you are bound to a search radius. I would like a return of lat, longs not confined to a location but rather where ever they occur. Or you can search by tags, which I am not certain this is the same as searching the caption.

Tags in app, is for tagging people. Assuming that search by tag is actually going to return results based off a search term not tagged people. I am getting an error in my script when trying to return lat/longs.

```
where = raw_input('Where would you like a map of?')
what = raw_input('What would you like to search Instagram for?')
search= api.tag_recent_media(tag_name=what)
map1 = folium.Map(location=geo(where), tiles='Stamen Toner', zoom_start=6)
    if ['location'] is not None:
        for media in search:
            lat_in=(media.location.point.latitude)
            long_in=(media.location.point.longitude)
            print lat_in +", " + long_in
            folium.Marker([lat_in, long_in], popup=content, icon=folium.Icon(icon='info-sign')).add_to(map1)
map1.save('map_instagram.html')  


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/dana/Desktop/free_instagram.py", line 16, in <module>
    lat_in=(media.location.point.latitude)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'location'
```

This combination works just fine, using media search but not using tag `name/media/recent`. Is there a better call I could be making perhaps to Media ID?

Comment: Update from advice sent in an email:

There isn't actually another option that will give you good coverage. However, you can do multiple searches from the original point.

Get original lat long, search, move point, search again, remove duplicates. 
It's actually the only way to get complete coverage as the api limits total response count.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27314439/423089